# Working with Mobius Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I want to find the transformation that maps $z_1 = 0,\,z_2 = 1,\,z_3 = \infty$ to $w_1 = 1,\,w_2 = 1+i,\,w_3 = i$. Under this mapping what is the image of the line $\text{Im}z = \text{Re}z$, the real axis and the imaginary axis.

So far I found that:

$$1 = \frac{b}{d},\quad 1+i = \frac{a+b}{c+d},\quad i = \frac{a}{c}\Rightarrow b=d,\,a = ic,\,id = -c.$$

this then gave me the transformation:

$$z\rightarrow w = \frac{z+1}{1-iz}$$

What do I do next to answer the question?

Comment: Do you know that Mobius transformations map generalised circles to generalised circles?

Comment: (A generalised circle being a circle or a straight line.)

Comment: ${\bf Im} z={\bf Re} z$ means $y=x$ so you take $z=x+ix$ and it's map will be . . .

Answer (score 0):

$$w=\frac{z+1}{1-iz} \Rightarrow z=\frac{w-1}{iw+1}$$
Now :
$$x+iy=z=\frac{u-1+iv}{1-v+iu}.\frac{(1-v)-iu}{(1-v)-iu}=\frac{(u-1)(1-v)+uv}{(1-v)^2+u^2}+i\frac{v(1-v)+u(1-u)}{(1-v)^2+u^2}$$
The image of the line $Imz=Rez$  :
$$x=y\Rightarrow u-1-uv+v+uv=v-v^2+u-u^2 \Rightarrow |w|=1$$